# .htaccess show image as if from another location when directly opening image

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

/       - this contains my main website on dog.com
/cat/       - this contains a second website on cat.com

If you access www.dog.com it shows the root
If you access www.cat.com it sends the user to everything in the /cat/ directory

What I would like to do is to access the files inside /images/ on the root from www.cat.com/images/

I have done this by using the following rewrite inside /cat/ : -

```
            RewriteRule ^images/(.*) /images/$1
```

**This works - **BUT**** if I try to access www.cat.com/images/logo.png it shows the logo, but upon opening the image as a standalone image the URL is: www.dog.com/images/logo.png
which I would like as www.cat.com/images/logo.png

**Is this even possible?**

I also have the following rewrite - incase this is conflicting with anything: -

```
            RewriteEngine On
            RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.dog\.com [NC]
            RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.cat.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Which is included inside /cat/, this hopefully stops www.dog.com/cat/whatever.html being spidered instead of www.cat.com/whatever.html